# PostgreSQL change part of a string to uppercase

Tags: postgresql

I have a field named `rspec` in a table `trace`.

So for now the field is like "Vol3/data/20070204_191426_FXBS.v3a".

All I need is a query to change it to the format "Vol3/data/20070204_191426_FXBS.V3A".

Comment: Do you only want to make the "extension" uppercase, or anything behind the second `/`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the current version:

```
select left(rspec, - 3)||upper(right(rspec, 3))
from trace
```

For older versions:

```
select substr(rspec, 1, length(rspec) - 3)||upper(substring(rspec from '...$'))
from trace
```

Comment: + 1 elegant use of the new `left()` with a negative length.

Answer (score 2):

Or, to cover all possibilities like

- file extensions of variable length: `abc123.jpeg`
- no file extension at all:  `abc123`
- dot as last character: `abc123.`
- multiple dots: `abc.123.jpg`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rspec  ~~ '%.%'
          THEN substring(rspec, E'^.*\\.')
            || upper(substring(rspec , E'([^.]*)$'))
          ELSE rspec
       END AS rspec 
FROM  (VALUES
         ('abc123.jpeg')
       , ('abc123')
       , ('abc123.')
       , ('abc.123.jpg')
         )  ASx(rspec); -- testcases
```

Explain:

If the string has no dot, use the string.
Else, take everything up to and including the last dot in the string.
Append everything after the last dot in upper case.